# Create a new table, sorted by st_area function in descending order

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, pg-tileserv

I have a very large table in postgis which has more than 10 million polygons and I wanted to create a function using this table for pg_tileserv but the problem is the size of table which takes too much time to load.

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE
    FUNCTION public.countries_name1(
        z integer, x integer , y integer )
     RETURNS  bytea
    AS $$
    declare
    result bytea;
    bounds geometry;
    simplify_tolerance integer;
    BEGIN
     -- Find the tile bounds
    SELECT ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y) AS geom INTO bounds; 
    simplify_tolerance   =(CASE 
    when z >= 16 then 0
    when z = 15 then 5
    when z = 14 then 25
    when z = 13 then 50
    when z = 12 then 100
    when z <= 11 then 150
    
     
    ELSE 1 END
    ) ;
    with
    mvtgeom AS (
   SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(ST_simplify(t.geom,simplify_tolerance), 3857), 
   bounds),t.fclass,x,y,z
   FROM large_polygon__table t
   WHERE ST_Intersects(t.geom, ST_Transform(bounds, 25833))
  
)
-- Serialize the result set into an MVT object
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom, 'public.countries_name1')
into result FROM mvtgeom;
RETURN result;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
IMMUTABLE -- Same inputs always give same outputs
STRICT -- Null input gets null output
PARALLEL SAFE;
```

This above code will be the function that I will use for generating vector tiles
I want to replace  this table(large_polygons_table) with a new table which will have the same data but it will be arranged in descending order by st_area like this->

```
create table large_polygons_orderByArea as
 (
   select * from large_polygons_table 
    order by st_area(geom) desc
  )
```

No matter how much time I give to this query it always get failed in between.
The reason for creating this table is that I can now limit the polygons in the above function for generating vector tiles at zoom levels like 6,7 etc.

Comment: Your area filter attempt would only make sense with a respective index - but note that PG can **either** use this **or** the spatial index! Note also that `ST_AsMVTGeom` *should* take care of simplification! Additionally, it is suggested to run this against the *Wagyu* backend. Find a way to reduce transformation calls - especially on large geometries.

Comment: need gist index and when zoomed out you can filter to only show larger features

Answer (score 3):

Instead of recreating the table, you can [create an index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) with you `ST_Area(geom)` and it will be used when requesting. If you really want to physically order your data along this index (for improvment of performance I guess) you can use the `CLUSTER` function using your newly created index (see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html)).

Comment: how can I create index using st_area(geom)?

Comment: Please look at the link I put on 'create an index'

Answer (score 2):

```
-- Create functional index
CREATE INDEX large_polygons_table_area_x 
  ON large_polygons_table (ST_Area(Geom));

-- Order output on functional index
SELECT * 
  FROM large_polygons_table 
  ORDER BY ST_Area(geom) 
  LIMIT 1000
```